# Performance impact using culture invariant resources

Tags: asp.net, resources, dll

I would like to know the performance impact of using the culture invariant resources instead of culture specific ones.

For example, we plan to deploy a website and not have any en-US resources. This is because our culture invariant resources are always identical to the en-US resources. Is this a good idea ? What are the cons?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you are planning to do and no significant performance issues in comparison to using culture specific resources.